# Build JSON as an array element

Tags: json, groovy

I have this JSON Builder Groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.StreamingJsonBuilder

class JSONTest {
    public static main(args) {       
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
        StreamingJsonBuilder builder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)
        builder.requests {
            name 'HSV Maloo'
            make 'Holden'
            year 2006
            country 'Australia'
        }
        String json = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(writer.toString())
        println json
    }
}
```

It produces output like this:

```
{
    "requests": {
        "name": "HSV Maloo",
        "make": "Holden",
        "year": 2006,
        "country": "Australia"
    }
}
```

But I want to make the output like this with the requests value as an array element:

```
{
    "requests": [{
        "name": "HSV Maloo",
        "make": "Holden",
        "year": 2006,
        "country": "Australia"
    }]
}
```

How I can change the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the form of the [StreamingJsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/StreamingJsonBuilder.html#call(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) DSL that allows you to pass an element name, a collection, and a closure to iterate over the collection with.

```
def requests = [
    [name: 'HSV Maloo', make: 'Holden', year: 2006, country: 'Australia']
]

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
StreamingJsonBuilder builder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)

builder.requests requests, { request ->
    name request.name
    make request.make
    year request.year
    country request.country
}

String json = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(writer.toString())
println json
```

Which will produce:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "name": "HSV Maloo",
            "make": "Holden",
            "year": 2006,
            "country": "Australia"
        }
    ]
}
```